Replacing shower drain and new drain won't install correctly
I had a leak due to old plumbers putty cracking so I decided it would also be a good time to replace the drain as the rubber hardens and what not. Old drain was a plastic Oatey casper and the new one is a similar Oatey. The drain pipe is metal. My problem is that when I tighten down the inner ring to squeeze down the rubber ring (beveled edge is at the top) the rubber ring is higher than the top of the metal drain pipe so it starts to warp and bend inward and is not watertight. I don't tighten it all the way down though as it just doesn't look or feel right. I feel like I've got the rubber ring as deep as it can go in the plastic drain. The pipe seems to be about 1 inch deeper than the pan. I've also flipped the rubber ring just to see what happens and similar issue of bulging inward. FYI I did seal off the edge of the drain with plumbers putty and confirmed visually that the leak was coming from the interior of the drain.
Looking at the old drain it seems like the rubber didn't have this bevel? Or maybe it was cut off? Then maybe glued in? I tried to take apart the old one but I can't budge the inner plastic ring. Maybe it was glued in?
Any thoughts on this? Or should I call a pro?

You can add pictures to your question.  It would help.

so you found the reason for plumber putty

Without pictures it is impossible to discern what your issue is.
